# ios - Nothing happens when pushing view controller to navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to push a view controller to a navigation controller, but nothing happens.

I have the following code in my appDelegate (which works fine it seems):

```
ViewController1* VC1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC1];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

And the following code in `VC1`:

```
ViewController2 *VC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
```

`VC2` gets initialised but isn't pushed to the navigation controller and therefor never presented. I have tried looking for answers for a while now but without success. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use Storyboards? It will save you a few headaches if you're new to ios. As for what's wrong, hard to tell from the limited code ... what does the VC2 init function do, are you sure your bounds are set up correctly?

Comment: Where in VC1 is the code that is supposed to push VC2?

Comment: I just want to do everything programatically, learn how stuff work I guess. I have tried starting the app up from VC2 and the view controller itself works fine, all views are displayed. There really isn't any more code related to the navigation controller, that I know of at least.

Comment: @SeanT It gets called when a button is pressed.

Comment: The `navigationController` property can be nil if you have an incorrect view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Where do you have that code in VC1? Have you loved self.navigationController to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: Where is this line of code called ?`[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];`

Comment: Logging the `navController` and making sure it's not nil is one of the first things I did. `[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];` is called on a button press. The method does some other things but nothing else related to `VC2`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that another navigation controller was active and had to be dismissed. The code posted was correct and all but I had totally missed another navigation controller.